# Como atualizar duas tabelas

Tags: c#

Boa noite! 
Estou com problemas em atualizar duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo no C#.

Obs. desta forma ele atualiza a tabela CONTATO, se eu inverto a sequencia do UPDATE ele atualiza a tabela CLIENTE, mas nunca as duas juntas. 
Segue o código:

//Método Editar

```
    public string Editar(DCadastro cadastro)
    {
        string resp = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        try
            {
            con.ConnectionString = Conexao.Cn;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            //// Inicia o escopo de transação
            SqlTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

            //// Informa o SqlCommand em qual escopo que se passará a transação de dados
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE CLIENTE SET CLIENTE.nome = @nome  WHERE CLIENTE.idCliente = @idCliente";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", cadastro.Nome);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCliente", cadastro.IdCliente);
            // Segunda consulta.
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE CONTATO SET CONTATO.idTipoContato = @idTipoContato, CONTATO.conteudo = @conteudo WHERE CONTATO.idCliente = @idCliente";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idTipoContato", cadastro.IdTipoContato);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conteudo", cadastro.Conteudo);


            resp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "Registro não foi inserido";
            // Encerra o escopo de transação passando as operações para Banco de Dados.
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw erro;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: Se esta ação tiver que ser feita SEMPRE nas duas tabelas para fazer sentido, você deveria usar uma transação.

Comment: Legal, vou pesquisar mais e obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine as duas tabelas com `JOIN` usando suas chaves primária e estrangeira.

A consulta vai ficar assim:

```
UPDATE
  CLIENTE 
INNER JOIN
  CONTATO 
ON
  CLIENTE.idCliente = CONTATO.idCliente
SET
  CLIENTE.nome = @nome, CONTATO.idTipoContato = @idTipoContato, CONTATO.conteudo = @conteudo 
WHERE
  CLIENTE.idCliente = @idCliente
```

Seu código vai ficar assim:

```
          try
          {
            con.ConnectionString = Conexao.Cn;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            //// Inicia o escopo de transação
            SqlTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

            //// Informa o SqlCommand em qual escopo que se passará a transação de dados
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;

            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE
                                  CLIENTE 
                                INNER JOIN
                                  CONTATO 
                                ON
                                  CLIENTE.idCliente = CONTATO.idCliente
                                SET
                                   CLIENTE.nome = @nome, CONTATO.idTipoContato = @idTipoContato, CONTATO.conteudo = @conteudo 
                                WHERE
                                   CLIENTE.idCliente = @idCliente";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", cadastro.Nome);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCliente", cadastro.IdCliente);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idTipoContato", cadastro.IdTipoContato);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conteudo", cadastro.Conteudo);


            resp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "Registro não foi inserido";
            // Encerra o escopo de transação passando as operações para Banco de Dados.
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw erro;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Muito bom!! Vou testar aqui! Mais uma vez Obrigado Augusto!!

Answer (score 1):

Olhando o exemplo na documentação, o recomendado seria efetuar a chamada do método ExecuteNonQuery a cada comando registrado. Ficaria assim:

```
command.CommandText ="Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.CommandText = "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

transaction.Commit();
Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
```

Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Deu certo com a chamada do ExecuteNonQuery em cada UPDATE ... Obrigado spartanroger!!